# Pandas apply function to unique values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, conditional-statements

I've been stuck on a Pandas problem and I can't seem to figure it out.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
ref, value, rule, result, new_column
a100, 25, high, fail, nan
a100, 25, high, pass, nan
a100, 25, medium, fail, nan
a100, 25, medium, pass, nan
a101, 15, high, fail, nan
a101, 15, high, pass, nan
a102, 20, high, pass, nan
```

I want to add a new column to this dataframe with the following pseudocode

For each unique value in ref, if `result = fail`, then `new_column = no` for all subsequent rows of the same "ref" value.

This is how the new dataframe should look like.

```
ref, value, rule, result, new_column
a100, 25, high, fail, no
a100, 25, high, pass, no
a100, 25, medium, fail, no
a100, 25, medium, pass, no
a101, 15, high, fail, no
a101, 15, high, pass, no
a102, 20, high, pass, yes
```

What I've managed to do is the following:

```
ref, value, rule, result, new_column
a100, 25, high, fail, no
a100, 25, high, pass, yes
```

This is achieved through the `df.loc` function.
But I need the function to apply to unique values, rather than each row.

Comment: Do you think `new_column = no` or `yes` ?

Comment: Can you add more rows to dataframe, becasue I think it is a bit unclear for me.

Comment: @jezrael Updated, please check. new_column = no for all instances where result = fail, for each unique ref value.

Comment: @Kvothe if your first two rows were swapped, would the new_column be yes, no, no, no or still be all no's?

Comment: @JonClements, I've updated the question. But if the rows were swapped. it would still be no, no, no for that value of "ref".

Comment: @Kvothe so, if I'm understanding correctly, then is the rule: "any ref that has a fail means the ref has failed"?

Comment: @JonClements, yes thats correct.

Comment: @JonClements - thank you for questions, it help me to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
print (df)
    ref  value    rule result  new_column
0  a100     25    high   pass         NaN
1  a100     25    high   fail         NaN
2  a100     25  medium   fail         NaN
3  a100     25  medium   pass         NaN
4  a101     15    high   fail         NaN
5  a101     15    high   pass         NaN
6  a102     20    high   pass         NaN

df['new_column']=df.groupby('ref')['result']
                   .transform(lambda x: 'no' if ((x=='fail').any()) else 'yes')
print (df)
    ref  value    rule result new_column
0  a100     25    high   pass         no
1  a100     25    high   fail         no
2  a100     25  medium   fail         no
3  a100     25  medium   pass         no
4  a101     15    high   fail         no
5  a101     15    high   pass         no
6  a102     20    high   pass        yes
```

Thank you [`Jon Clements`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102563/pandas-apply-function-to-unique-values-in-column/39102649?noredirect=1#comment65554409_39102649) for another solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('ref')['result']
                     .transform(lambda L: (L == 'fail').any())
                     .replace({True: 'no', False: 'yes'})

print (df)
    ref  value    rule result new_column
0  a100     25    high   pass         no
1  a100     25    high   fail         no
2  a100     25  medium   fail         no
3  a100     25  medium   pass         no
4  a101     15    high   fail         no
5  a101     15    high   pass         no
6  a102     20    high   pass        yes
```

Comment: Umm... I had `df.groupby('ref')['result'].transform(lambda L: (L == 'fail').any()).replace({True: 'no', False: 'yes'})`